# SSL client authentication with a certificate with non exportable private key

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

We have a thick java client and do SSL server and client authentication.

This scenario is on Mac OS.

Our users get a certificate with non exportable private key.

Now if i want to do SSL client authentication it fails for this certificate. Below is the code snippet which i am using`to crearte the key store( have the certificate alias with me) with which i create the KeyManager which is in turn passed to the SSLContext.

```
    KeyStore systemKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("KEYCHAINSTORE");
    systemKeyStore.load(null, null);

    resultKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    resultKeyStore.load(null, null);

    if (certalias != null && !certalias.trim().equals("") && systemKeyStore.containsAlias(certalias) && systemKeyStore.isKeyEntry(certalias)) {

        try {
            Key key = systemKeyStore.getKey(certalias, "t".toCharArray());
            Certificate certs[] = systemKeyStore.getCertificateChain(certalias);
            resultKeyStore.setKeyEntry(certalias, key, "randompw".toCharArray(), certs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

The line 
`Key key = systemKeyStore.getKey(certalias, "t".toCharArray()); fails as it` the key object returned is null

Question is , is it possible to do SSL client authentication with a certificate with private key marked as non exportable ?

**UPDATE**
As mentioned below in one of my comments. I tried using the default SSL context property by passing the SSL system properties. But still it did not work. Below is my code for that

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "KEYCHAINSTORE");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "KEYCHAINSTORE");



    if (socketFactory == null) {
        // socketFactory = initializeSocketFactory(Settings.isCertificateAuth(), Settings.getClientCertAlias());
        socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    }
```

Let me know if i need to provide any further details

Comment: It's not clear what error you get. Does systemKeyStore.getKey() return null or isn't the private key accepted? How do you know key is null? BTW empty catch blocks are bad and you'll never know what the actual error was. Also post the code where you get systemKeyStore.

Comment: @vempo i debugged and found that key returned is null...and then since i am trying to set the key entry with null key i am getting an exception there...i have updated my question about how i am getting the system key store

Comment: You shouldn't need all this code. In fact you shouldn't need any of it, just set the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and associated system properties to use the KEYCHAINSTORE directly. You should certainly not need to use a second JKS keystore, or attempt to load the keys or certificates yourself.

Comment: @EJP..thanks for the reply...i will try that and post my updates here...but one basic question...will the certificates with private key mark non exportable will work with that ?

Comment: If it doesn't it's pointless. But if it's non-exportable you certainly won't be able to export it into a second keystore.

Comment: even if i use the initial key store...it does not work

Comment: Also adding system properties and default SSL Context factory did not work...post updated with that code

Comment: The type of the keychainstore is, err, `KEYCHAINSTORE`, as proven by your original `KeyStore.getInstance()` call. Not JKS.

Comment: changed to KEYCHAINSTORE but still the same problem...the keymanager variable in the SSLContextFactory seems to have empty credentials map and serveraliascache for that certificate (both with my implementation as well with default implementation )...i don't know if this matters

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you have now set `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType`, as mentioned in m previous comment.

Comment: i have made the changes but still it does not work